# Json Help, need to populate according to the selected drop down

Tags: jquery, json

I want to get the data according to the drop down selected

As here i am making transaction statement , in which user has to enter the from date and end dat , on basic on which the in-between data will be populated.

I got stuck at some point , don't know how to resolve.

this is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jatin/CvHta/30/)

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jatin/CvHta/30/
```

Comment: problem with serializejson method

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(frmSerialize, function(fk, fv) {
                if (fk % 2 === 0) {
                    monthVal = fv;
                // console.log(monthVal);
                } 
                else {
                    yearVal = fv;
                // console.log(yearVal);
                }

                $.each(myJsonData, function(tk, tv) {
                    //console.log(tk);
                    $.each(tv, function(yk, yv) {
                        //console.log(yk +' '+ yv);
                        $.each(yv, function(mk, mv) {
                            // console.log("asd");
                            if (yearVal == yk) {

                                $('#result').append(fv + ' ' + yk + ' to ' + mk + ' ' + mv + '<br />');
                                console.log(yk + ' ' + mk + ' ' + mv);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```

As much i understood from above, in frmSerialize you have contraints(from and to dates) to test for and you are looping using this...bad practice..not only in JavaScript..this is not basic coding practice..

To correct this in simple way...run each for JSON data...test the frmSerialize array for each of them...